# Switching Users without inputing passwords in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, security, passwords, session

I have set up 2 users both as administrators. It is a home computer and we do not require password protection. I am the normal user and have managed to set up so that I login without having to enter password .

However whenever my family switches to his user the login screen forces him to write his a password, and when i switch back from his session to mine Im forced to put my password again.

Is it possible to set-up windows 10, so that we can simply switch users without inputting any passwords?

Comment: If there are no passwords all you have to do hit `switch users`, select the user, then provide an empty password.

Comment: already tried leaving it in blank however windows 10 uses a microsoft account so im forced to put a password to it

Comment: You can disconnect your account from your Microsoft Account.  You are not required to link your Microsoft Account.  That is an 1000% optional feature of both Windows 8.x and Windows 10.  You won't be able to seamlessly switch users of your accounts are linked to Microsoft Accounts.